# Simular comandos cd .. o cambiar directorio con c++ y QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy intentando implementar en c++ con un vector que pueda simular por ejemplo el comando cd .. de esa manera podría volver a mi anterior ruta o tambien pueda guardar la ruta actual para poder mostrarla. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
//store the paths you iterate
std::vector<QString> paths;
paths.emplace_back("first path");
paths.emplace_back("second path");
if(input_path == "cd"){
    QDir new_path(paths.back());
    new_path.cd();
    paths.emplace_back(new_path.absolutePath());
}

//back to previous path, stl split back and pop_back to two actions for the sake of exception safe
auto const path = paths.back();
paths.pop_back();
```

Pero lo que quiero es precisamente que funcione por lo que de momento no se muy bien como implementar esto. Tenia pensado en guardar la ruta que introduzco por ejemplo hago:
cd C:/Myusuario
lo guardo en el vector new_path.cd(C:/Myusuario); y luego si quiero volver atras llamo esto:
auto const path = paths.back();
paths.pop_back();

No se si sea buena idea por lo que les consulto a vosotros como expertos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tendrías que preguntarte es: ¿para qué quiero cambiar el directorio actual? ¿Es solo un programa para tí mismo, para que te resulte más cómodo trabajar desde terminal? ¿Es un simple intento, o juego de programación para ver qué se puede hacer? ¿O es parte de un proyecto más grande, y una de las cosas que debe hacer, es cambiar el directorio actual para cualquier otra razón?

## Bash

Si es para poder trabajar más cómodamente desde una terminal `bash`, eso ya existe:

Los comandos `pushd` y `popd`:

```
$ pushd nuevo_directorio # Ahora estás en nuevo_directorio
$ pushd otro_directorio # Ahora estás en otro_directorio
$ popd # Ahora estás en nuevo_directorio
$ popd # Ahora estás en el directorio original.
```

Cada llamada a `pushd` guarda el nuevo directorio en una pila, así vas acumulando un historial de llamadas. Cada llamada a `popd`, vuelve al directorio anterior, borrando el último (el tope), del historial de llamadas.

Si tu historial va a tener como máximo tamaño uno (es decir, ir y volver, y ya está), `cd` ya provee una manera de volver al directorio anterior:

```
$ cd nuevo_directorio # Cambia el directorio actual
$ cd - # Vuelve al directorio donde estabas
```

Si estás en Windows, ni idea.

## Experimentando con C++

Si es, sencillamente, para ver lo que puedes hacer desde C++, puedes hacer uso de `system`.

Sencillamente, llamas a comandos de `bash` (o de `MS-DOS` si estás en Windows, o del lenguaje de terminal asociado a tu sistema operativo):

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

system("pushd nuevo_directorio");
system("popd");
```

O con `cd`, o lo que quieras.

Si es engorroso trabajar con `system` (`system` recibe cadenas de bajo nivel, y a lo mejor quieres trabajar con `std::string`s), tienes otras dos maneras. Con `Qt`:

```
QDir::setCurrent("nuevo_directorio");
```

o con `boost`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

boost::filesystem::current_path("nuevo_directorio");
```

Evidentemente, con estas dos soluciones, además de ser multiplataforma (sea Windows, Linux, Android, etc), puedes trabajar con cadenas de alto nivel, llevar tu historial en un `std::stack` o un `std::vector`, o sus correspondientes tipos de `Qt`, etc.

Adicionalmente, puedes comprobar que el directorio exista (o fichero, en caso de que quieras abrir un fichero en este directorio), pasando las rutas relativas a absolutas con `boost::filesystem::canonical`, que lanza una excepción si la ruta dada no existe o hay algún tipo de problemas de permisos:

```
try {
  ruta_file = boost::filesystem::canonical(path_dir);
} catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& err) {
  std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl; // Mostrar el error
}

// path_dir es una ruta absoluta a partir de aquí.
```

## Proyecto real

Quizás eres víctima del *problema XY*, que consiste en buscar una solución a un problema diferente al real. Tu problema real puede ser que no puedes abrir un fichero por culpa de una ruta incorrecta o falta de permisos, pero en vez de solucionar el problema de abrir un fichero, intentas solucionarlo cambiando de directorio.

En cualquier caso, no defiendo, como solución, cambiar el directorio actual de la aplicación. Eso puede darte verdaderos quebraderos de cabeza a la larga. ¿Y si se lanza una excepción después de cambiar de directorio y antes de volver al directorio original? ¿Cómo te aseguras de siempre estás en el directorio que deseas? ¿Y si tienes un error en tu histórico de directorios y te mueves a directorios imprevistos?

Para ello, haz uso del principio [KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS): *Keep it simple stupid* Por supuesto, no te estoy insultando. Es una principio de diseño. La solución más simple, si tu problema real es abrir ficheros, es, por supuesto, asegurarte que las rutas sean correctas.

Si tienes problemas para abrir el fichero, puede ser porque:

- el usuario no te lo está indicando bien. Problema del usuario de tu aplicación, y no tuyo como programador. El usuario debe saber desde dónde está ejecutando la aplicación, para algo es él quien la lanza. Como mucho podrías informar al usuario de que hay un problema para abrir el fichero.
- o porque tienes problemas de permisos. Quizás el fichero o ficheros que quieres abrir están en un directorio sin permiso de ejecución para la aplicación, por ejemplo. En cualquier caso, nuevamente, es problema del usuario, dado que es un problema de entorno.
- si la aplicación tiene permisos suficientes y el usuario te da la ruta relativa del directorio correctamente, quizás no estás guardando la cadena bien. Quizás guardaste un salto de línea, o quizás el nombre del fichero contiene espacios y solo estás guardnaod parte de la cadena como ruta.

Si aún así insistes, la cualquiera de las soluciones dadas arriba en C++ dadas arriba te debería valer.